# node rsa base 128 encoding giving unknown encoding error while encrytping

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, rsa, radix

At present i am using base64 encoding to encrypt and it worked as per initial requirements. Now we are in a situation to reduce the encrypted string length ,with this goal i am trying base128 but ended up with unknown encoding error

Used NodeRSA module encryption library, with base 64. tried to use base128 instead of base64 ended in unknown encoding error

```
//working version with base64
// encrypt
const encryptToken = publicKey.encrypt(inputString, 'base64');

// decrypt
const decryptToken = privateKey.decrypt(Buffer.from(encryptToken, 'base64'), 'utf8');
```

what base encoding should i be using to reduce the encrypted string length?

Comment: First off, do you really need to encode the data at all? Sending/storing the raw byte array is the most efficient. Secondly, if you must encode, then what are the acceptable characters in the channel you are using? Finally, the most common encoding format with a slightly higher density than base64 is base85. You can find node packages for base85 encoding, but make sure the characters it outputs are legal in your channel.

Comment: I shall try base85 if it didnt go well,let me explore further on raw byte array options thx